# The height of a tangential trapezoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $ABCD$ be a tangential trapezoid, touching the circle $k(O;r)$. Show that the height of the trapezoid $h=2r$.

Let $M$ and $N$ be the points on  $AB$ and $DC$, respectively, at which the circle is tangent $\Rightarrow OM\perp AB, ON\perp CD$ (The radius of a circle is perpendicular to the tangent line through its endpoint on the circle's circumference.) What can we do next?

Answer (score 1):

Proving angle $MON = 180^{o}$ should complete the proof, as that would mean the line $MN$ is the diameter of the circle.
In order to prove this draw a horizontal line passing through the $O$ which touches the side $AD$ at a point say $E$. Angle $MOE$ is $90^o$ (can be proved by using the fact that the line is horizontal and sum of angles of a quadrilateral is $360^o$), Similarly Angle $NOE$ is $90^o$. Thus Angle $MON$ is $180^o$